# How to prevent an embeded type-form to scroll after loading

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typeform

I am building a ReactJS application and have a typeform which I embed to the middle of the page. Problem is that as soon as the Type-Form loads in the https://www.npmjs.com/package/@heyjobs/react-typeform-embed

Code:

```
class OverTheCounter extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="OtcContainer">
        <div className="overTheCounterPage">
          {/*<img  src={image1} alt="HeaderImage" />
      <h1 >Over the counter</h1>
   </div>
   <OtcIcon />
   */}
        </div>
        <ParallaxHeader />
        <div className="typeForm">
          <ReactTypeformEmbed
            className="typeForm"
            url="https://xxx.typeform.com/to/XXX"
          />
        </div>
        <OtcIcon />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default OverTheCounter;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for the react embed component you're using I can't comment or explain how it works. However I recently created and maintain a web components library (which from my tests works well with React).

You can install it with

```
npm install typeform-elements
```

And import the embed library into your apps entry point with:

```
import 'typeform-elements/dist/embed';
```

And finally use the component as so...

```
<typeform-standard url="{typeform_url}"></typeform-standard>
```

The embed component has a few attributes you can use and [learn about here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typeform-elements#embed). And if things don't work, open an issue!

Comment: this is not a react specific solution

Comment: Does it need to be though? It's a wrapper for the embed sdk and provides elements that are understood by the DOM/Window/BOM (like a div or an iframe). More than sufficient, and is framework agnostic (so any web dev may use it).

Comment: I just get window is undefined if I try and use it in a react app

Comment: Is your code in a public repo that I could see? (I can try to help from there)

Comment: Silly me, its because I server side rendering. swapped `import "typeform-elements/dist/embed";` for `if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  require("typeform-elements/dist/embed");
}` and it works like a charm. thank you so much.

Comment: Oh ho, that just added over 200kb to my bundle. Working on module exports any time soon?

Comment: So the components themselves are individually exported, but I haven't tinkered with registering them (rather the import suggestion I gave gives you an iife). So technically `import { TypeformStandard } from 'typeform-elements';` would give you the component, you'd just need to ensure its registered to the DOM.